# Get UserID identity asp .net core mvc

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, userid

i am using asp.net core mvc to make a web app and using identity .
[Database Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ7XU.png)
this is my database excluding Templates all were created with identity.
[Templates Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGhQJ.png)
this Templates table.
what i want to do is store the used id who upload the file to the table Templates.
I first thought of using user id as a foreign key but didn't work.
Is there any way to do that ?
one more thing the Template table get's data when the user upload an image in a form and submit so the controller takes all the data and saves it in the db.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/get+user+id+in+controller+asp.net+core
i found the answer here !
i used this:
var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) ;